# Google Captcha fails at validate the captcha response from server side

Tags: recaptcha

I am using google captcha v2 in my site,

1. Showing captcha `works`
2. Generating response string `works`
3. Validation inside the server side (api : https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify) `fails`

with following html error

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/><title>Sorry...</title><style> body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #000; }</style></head><body><div><table><tr><td><b><font face=sans-serif size=10><font color=#4285f4>G</font><font color=#ea4335>o</font><font color=#fbbc05>o</font><font color=#4285f4>g</font><font color=#34a853>l</font><font color=#ea4335>e</font></font></b></td><td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 50%\"><div style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;\">Sorry...</div></td></tr></table></div><div style=\"margin-left: 4em;\"><h1>We're sorry...</h1><p>... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.</p></div><div style=\"margin-left: 4em;\">See <a href=\"https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640\">Google Help</a> for more information.<br/><br/></div><div style=\"text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;\"><a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google Home</a></div></body></html>
```

Message :

`We're sorry... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.`

anyone faced this issue ? any work around for this ?

Answer (score 0):

it was related with setting of IPV6, Please run Google Search for “What is my IP”. If it returns as ipv6, you might have to force it to ipv4.